# PHP oop how can i call dynamic function name

Tags: php

I have a method `display()` in the book class.

```
$name = 'display()';
$book = new Book('PHP Object-Oriented Solutions', 300);

$book->$name;
```

How can i call display method using `$book->$name`

Comment: Did you try `$book->$name`? what was the error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of the PHP Manual. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: when I use $book->$name it says Notice: Undefined property: Book::$display()

Comment: Remove `()` from `$name`

Comment: Removing () from $name gives Undefined property: Book::$display

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Book::$display() suggests to me that you don't have a method named 'display' in your Book class.

Comment: Try: $name = 'display'; $book->{$name}(); or u can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell PHP that you're trying to execute a method, not in the variable itself, but within the actual code:

```
$name = 'display';
$book = new Book('PHP Object-Oriented Solutions', 300);

$book->$name();
```

Otherwise, as you have seen, it will treat `$name` as a property name, and rightly so ... If you have *both* a property and a method named 'display', there wouldn't be a way to distinguish between the two using what you've tried.

Comment: Isn't that going to run the `$name()` first?

Comment: No, the lexer sees the OOP context and would ignore a regular function named `display()`.

Comment: wasn't sure about it and kind of couldn't test it :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way (imo at least) is to use something like:

```
$name = 'display';
$book = new Book('PHP Object-Oriented Solutions', 300);

call_user_func([$book, $name]); // This looks cleaner and/or more obvious on first sight.
// call_user_func_array([$book, $name], $arrayOfArguments);

// And as @Narf suggested (and I agree cuz we move forward)
call_user_func([$book, $name], ... $arrayOfArguments);
```

And yes you can pass parameters to this function, that will be passed to the function, but you have to list them after the callable array. in order to avoid doing that (hard to maintain and not always what you want) you can use `call_user_func_array` which accepts an array of arguments as second argument that is passed to the callable.

[`call_user_func` Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

[`call_user_func_array` Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Argument unpacking FTW: `call_user_func([$book, $name], ... $argsArray);`

Comment: ~Lol, that is if we are throwing 5.6 out the window (not mentioning others since EOL), but will edit~ Apparently I am dumb enough to forget they are 5.6 feature ... *facepalm*

Comment: That's a PHP 5.6 feature. ;) The EOLd versions can RIP.